# JSON Parsing Issue - 'S' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net, appsettings

I have the following JSON in `appsettings` file , it has a connection string.

```
 {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Warning"
        }
      },
      "ApplicationInsights": {
        "InstrumentationKey": "8eje88w0-1509-4ae0-b58c-1a7ee5b9c7e4"
      },
       "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnString": "Server=MYPC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CoreService.Mark;Trusted_Connection=True;"
      },
      "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }
```

But upon executing the program.I keep getting the following error.I tried to find any errors,but could not locate any.Please advice

```
Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: Could not parse the JSON file.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'S' is an invalid escapable character within a JSON string. The string should be correctly escaped. LineNumber: 10 | BytePositionInLine: 42
```

Comment: Back slashes must be escaped.

Comment: either use the forward slash, or use the backslash twice

Comment: Json string definition from Json.org: https://www.json.org/img/string.png

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your `ConnectionStrings. DefaultConnString` field, you're escaping `S` (before `SQLExpress;`). As the error suggests, you can't do that.

You can fix this by adding another escape character (backslash, `\`) in front of the pre-existing one. Backslashes are escapable characters and the end result will be the wanted one, you'll get one backslash in that position.

Answer (score 1):

write this:

> .\\SQLEXPRESS

you must write double backslash